# Автоматическое скачивание файла на js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно сделать автоматическое скачивание файла при переходе на страницу, чтобы пользователь не нажимал "скачать". По типу перейти на главную страницу сайта и автоматическое скачивание пошло

Comment: делаешь ссылку на файл указываешь ей атрибут download и вызываешь click

Comment: а можно так скачать папку?

Comment: нет, потому что скачивать можно только файлы

Comment: понял, спасибо)

Comment: Только если архивом

Comment: @HTOHOT, который является файлом ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯